# Can I pool studies in a meta analysis with binary and continuous outcomes?

Tags: binary-data, meta-analysis, continuous-data, metafor

I'm currently completing a meta-analysis (in r using the meta/metafor package) looking at predictors of treatment response in patients suffering from a particualr mental disorder (psychosis).

Some studies report the outcome variable as a binary variable (responder vs non-responders) and others report the outcome as a continuous variable.

I would ideally like to combine these different studies to increase the statistical power.

My question is **whether it's appropriate to convert the effect sizes (i.e. standardised mean difference and correlation) to a common effect size (e.g Cohen's D) to be able to pool the studies**.

Any advice (or signpost to relevant papers) would be greatly appreciated.

Please excuse any faux pas in writing this query, as I'm new to the forum.

Comment: Perhaps this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236600/can-i-combine-binary-and-continuous-data-to-meta-analyze-prospective-changes-ove?rq=1 might help?